# How to clear the error in this code in php?

Tags: php

```
    <?php

           $phpContent = '<?php 

           session_start(); 

           include("../conn.inc.php");

           $id = $_SESSION["gameid"]; 

           $select_content = mysql_query("select * from game_details where id=".$id);

           $arr_content = mysql_fetch_array($select_content);

           echo $arr_content["name"];exit;


     ?>
     ';

        fwrite($phpFile, $phpContent);
        fclose($phpFile);
?>
```

In this code, I am selecting the datas from the database of a particular value of id stored in $id. The code in $phpContent, I am writing it into a file,it shows this error,when I am opening that written file:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean

Can anyone say how to eliminate this error ?

```
   conn.inc.php
    <?php
      error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
      $db_host = "localhost";
      $db_user = "root";
      $db_name = "pixo";
      $db_pwd =  "mysql";
      $connection=mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd);
      mysql_select_db($db_name);


     ?>
```

Comment: can you please share conn.inc.php file code.

Comment: I have added the code in conn.inc.php

Comment: Have you echo out your id and made sure it's not empty? Is the table name correct?

Comment: the id has value in it..but i dnt if the select statment is correct in picking the id, the double quotes is corect or not.

Comment: Nobody here to help me on this.

Comment: Is the id an integer? if not use quotes in the select statement: `select * from game_details where id=\'$id\'"`

Answer (score 1):

Your issues with `mysql_select_db` you have forgot to pass `$connection` as second parameter please change your code with below code.

```
<?php
      error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
      $db_host = "localhost";
      $db_user = "root";
      $db_name = "pixo";
      $db_pwd =  "mysql";
      $connection=mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd);
      mysql_select_db($db_name,$connection);
?>
```

[More About mysql_select_db](http://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/mysql_select_db.php)

But my advice is now days `mysql_select_db` is not secure please go with MySQLi Functions [More About Mysqli](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp)

Hope above code will helps you. you forgot pass `$connection` parameter.

Comment: its showing false(bool) when var_dump() the select statement variable

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your mysql requête is returning FALSE, var_dump your $select_content var to see what it is returning exactly.

Comment: its showing in the output as bool(false) ..like this...how to rectify this ?

Comment: how to correct this value of id..its not selecting the values in the $id from database